# How can I keep focus on a window after the mouse left said window

Tags: windows-10, window-focus

Here is a common example: I open some mp3 file on VLC. The VLC window appears and I realize the volume is too low/high. Thinking I automatically have the focus on this window I *just opened*, I use the mouse scroll to adjust the volume... Nothing happens!

The focus is apparently not on that window because the mouse pointer is not over the window. When I mouse over the window I can adjust the volume using the scroll wheel.

Second common use case: I am reading a webpage and absent-mindedly drift away from the browser window. Now when I scroll down to read the rest of the story, I have to put the mouse *over* the browser window to be able to scroll down with the mouse.

I have 2 screens so my problems are even worse than that...

I upgraded from Windows 8.1 (Pro 64-bits) and have never experienced this problem before.

Is there a setting somewhere to switch to the previous established behaviour?

Comment: Does [this](http://winaero.com/blog/turn-on-xmouse-active-window-tracking-focus-follows-mouse-pointer-feature-in-windows-8-1-windows-8-and-windows-7/) page help?

Comment: No I saw that and tried it. But When I mouseout the window loses focus as one would expect...

Comment: You lost focus after mouse left **and clicked elsewhere**. Moving wouldn't lost focus.

Comment: No Chris.C, the behaviour you describe is what I used to know before Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lifehacker gave me the answer!](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-disable-windows-10s-inactive-window-scrolling-1727952625)

The problem is caused by a new Windows 10 feature called "Inactive Window Scrolling". Fortunately, the Windows settings page lets you disable it:

[image]